# Как задать столбцу GridView отдельную вьюху?

Tags: php, yii2

В столбце очень много всего и одной лямбдой не обойтись. Мне надо вынести столбец в отдельный файл. Не нашел нигде как такое сделать стандартными средствами. Т.е. мне надо что-то вроде свойства itemView в ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что решил так:

```
$getRenderer = function($view) {
    return function($model) use($view) {
        return $this->render($view, ['model' => $model]);
    };
};

// и в столбце

'value' => $getRenderer('my_view'),
```

Но очень надеюсь что все-же предусмотрено какое-то стандартное решение типа того же itemView у ListView.