# Вставить HTML код в GridView Yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2, gridview

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос.

есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код таблицы:

```
<?php

 use yii\helpers\Html;
 use kartik\grid\SerialColumn;
 use yii\grid\CheckboxColumn;
 use yii\grid\ActionColumn;
 use kartik\grid\GridView;

    echo GridView::widget([
        'condensed'=>true,
        'hover'=>true,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'panel' => [
            'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Countries</h3>',
            'type'=>'success',
            'before'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Create Country', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
            'after'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Reset Grid', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
            'footer'=>false
        ],
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn'
            ],
        [
           // тут должна быть кнопка.
        ]
    ],
]); ?>
```

В это пустое поле, я бы хотел вставить html конопку, которая будет разворачиваться pop up меню с помощью js.

Как это можно будет сделать?

Примерный код кнопки:

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недавно возник такой же [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738842/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%83-gridview-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%85%D1%83). Решил так.

```
$getRenderer = function($view) {
    return function($model) use($view) {
        return $this->render($view, ['model' => $model]);
    };
};

// и в столбце

'value' => $getRenderer('my_view')
```

Видимо стандартного способа указать вьюху в качестве столбца не существует.

Comment: Хм. Думал, что есть другой способ, просто вставить HTML. 
Понял, спасибо за информацию. С: